# Regex to find the number between some tags

Tags: java, regex

I have a document that has a bunch of these:

```
<vcsRevisionKey>12345</vcsRevisionKey>
```

I want to come up with a java regex to get the numbers only. Thank you.

Comment: You can use this site for testing out Java regex's: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Will it _always_ be between those _exact_ tags? If not -- i.e. you're trying to parse [X]HTML with regex -- [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) may be an entertaining (if largely useless) read.

Comment: Yes it'll always be between those tags.

Comment: To continue QPaysTaxes' point, you either should use an appropriate markup parser or, in the case you will always want `vcsRevisionKey` tag value, just use `<vcsRevisionKey>(\d+)</vcsRevisionKey>` as your regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following simple regex :

```
>(\d+)<
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cN7kM0/1)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I think you should use `<vcsRevisionKey>(\d+)</vcsRevisionKey>` as your regex.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work on tags with attributes as well:

```
<vcsRevisionKey(\s[^>]*)?>(\d+)</vcsRevisionKey>
```